# How to make Application ontop of all windows and allow message box to be shown correctly

Tags: c#, modal-dialog

I am writing an application, that on specific conditions must make my application ontop of all other windows applications.

I do this in timer code as shown below that runs every 10 ms. That is fine. However if i need to throw a message box if there is an error then the messagebox ok button cannot be pressed because the form is made topmost every 10 ms - The button can be seen but you cant click ok.

Assumably because the first time you click the button brings the errorbox modal and by the time you click the ok button 10 ms has passed and the form is now ontop again.

How can i fix this issue ?

**Timer**

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = true;
    this.TopMost = true;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
}
```

**Show an Error**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Some error occured");
}
```

Comment: You are confused about the terms "(Always) On Top" and "Modal". A messagebox is always modal, and that doesn't mean that it always is visible. Just make sure making your form non-topmost before showing the messagebox (and make it topmost again afterwards, if necessary).

Comment: @elgonzo hi - making this.TopMost = false before throwing the messagbox does not work

Comment: When you mean "modal on top of all other windows", you really mean "nothing can be done with the system (other apps) until this window we're talking about closes", correct? Or does this mean "modal and on top of all of *this app's* windows, not necessarily other applications"? Also, if you tried what elgonzo suggested, by setting `TopMost` immediately before the call to `MessageBox.Show(), the timer will tick, and it will be set back to true.

Comment: @Steve yes i need this application to be ontop of all other windows applications - this works fine with the code above but the message box then does not function as expected i.e you cant acknowledge an error. When i tried elgonzo's suggestion ( other applications can now be ontop which is not what i want.) sorry if my question was a little unclear.

Comment: @user1438082, what do you mean the "messagebox not function as expected"? I mean, it just shows with an OK button, and it disappears when you click the OK button. There is nothing else to a message box. Please be precise in your explanations, as this question is on the verge of derailing into a discussion thread (at which point it will die and you will still struggle with your problem)

Comment: @elgonzo "The button can be seen but you cant click ok."

Comment: @user1438082, messagebox "OK" button, or button in your application form...?

Comment: @elgonzo messagebox "OK" button

Comment: @user1438082, try something like `this.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => MessageBox.Show("my text")) );`. If this doesn't help, then i don't know. If it or something else helps, it would be appreciated if you could write a short answer to your question, briefly explaining what the solution/fix to your problem is.

Comment: @elgonzo - that doesn't work - thanks for trying - there must be a solution....

Comment: @elgonzo got it - see below

Comment: A good way to get help, by the way, would be to post a very small program (that compiles and runs) that shows the problem, which would probably be pretty easy in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.TopMost == true)
        this.TopMost = true;

    this.Visible = true;

    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MessageBox.Show("Some error occured");
}
```

Comment: Interesting that the test for the TopMost flag made a difference. It looks like WinForms doesn't make an internal check whether the form is already top-most, but unconditionally sends a message to the GUI message queue. As it seems, the timer period of 10ms is sufficiently short so that the GUI message queue becomes clogged, which in turn prevents posting of further window messages (such as the click event on the MessageBox button, which is normally also processed by the GUI's main message queue). But that is all just me guessing; i also could be totally wrong about it...